# Coding Help (If Statements)

Tags: java, if-statement

**Let's say I have a sample code, something like this**

```
public double {method} ()
{
if (stringThatCalledThisMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) // x = A String
{
return 100 ;
}
else if (stringThat....equalsIgnoreCase("y"))         // y = A String
{
return 999 ;
}
```

**How would I call for the string that called that method?** 
(In this instance any string can call for the method and it will always be different)

(Using **this** does not work as I get an error saying "Cannot find Symbol |  symbol: method equalsIgnoreCase(String)

**I am trying to convert a string to a double** (Not sure if there is an easier way)

Comment: pass `stringThatCalledThisMethod` as method param `double {method} (String stringThatCalledThisMethod)`

Comment: `double x = Double.parseDouble("1234.5678");`

Comment: You want to know the name of the method that called another method from inside the called method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string to double, following code should do:

```
public double doubleString(String text){

        return Double.parseDouble(text);

}
```

You might want to catch **NumberFormatException** to handle the case of invalid value to cast as Double.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you need name of the caller method and then compare it.
As per my understanding this is what you need.

```
String callerMethodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getMethodName();
```

Note that you might need to replace the 2 with 1.

Other way could be sending method name as param in your 2nd method like:-

```
public double method2(String callerMethodName){

}
```